# VBA code to compare two worksheets and add the missing lines

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop, countif

I have below code which is working but taking time (around 10 min) and sometimes it is going in to not responding mode as my data has around 60k lines.

What i am trying to do is to compare values in column A of both worksheets paste the entire line(A-X) in to sh1 if the value is present in sh2 but not in sh1.

Can someone help to if there is better, faster and efficient way than this.

```
Sub t()
Dim sh1 As Worksheet, sh2 As Worksheet, c As Range
Set sh1 = Workbooks(WK1).Sheets(sheet1)
Set sh2 = Workbooks(WK2).Sheets(sheet1)
    For Each c In sh2.Range("A2", sh2.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
        If Application.CountIf(sh1.Range("A:A"), c.Value) = 0 Then
            c.Resize(, 24).Copy sh1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)(2)
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Getting a range is slow so minimize the number of range() calls. Sort both sheets so you don't have to do a countif() or grab the whole range of the lookup values into an array and do a lookup in the array. .Ohh and there is an intersect operator which could work pretty well here as well

Answer (score 0):

try add
`Application.ScreenUpdate=False Application.EnableEvents = False`
on start and
`Application.ScreenUpdate=True  Application.EnableEvents = True`
on end of code. it should speed up a whole code. like below. You can add userform with progress bar to show actual status.

```
Sub t()
Dim sh1 As Worksheet, sh2 As Worksheet, c As Range
Application.ScreenUpdate=False
Application.EnableEvents = False
Set sh1 = Workbooks(WK1).Sheets(sheet1)
Set sh2 = Workbooks(WK2).Sheets(sheet1)
For Each c In sh2.Range("A2", sh2.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
    If Application.CountIf(sh1.Range("A:A"), c.Value) = 0 Then
        c.Resize(, 24).Copy sh1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)(2)
    End If
Next
Application.ScreenUpdate=True 
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

\\ edited \\

Try code below. there is no necesary to check all range by worksheetfunction every lane. find method is faster

```
Sub t()
Dim sh1 As Worksheet, sh2 As Worksheet, c As Range
Dim str_LookUp As String, rng_FindRange As Range
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
Set sh1 = Workbooks(WK1).Sheets(sheet1)
Set sh2 = Workbooks(WK2).Sheets(sheet1)
For Each c In sh2.Range("A2", sh2.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
str_LookUp = c.Text
Set rng_FindRange = sh1.Range("A:A").Find(str_LookUp, , , xlWhole)
If rng_FindRange Is Nothing Then
    c.Resize(, 24).Copy sh1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)(2)
End If
Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: I have added them but it is same mate. Not much difference in terms of time it is taking to finish.

Comment: I am trying to run it but getting a type mismatch error @ Set rng_FindRange = sh2.Range("A:A").Find(str_LookUp, rng_FindRange.Address, , xlWhole). Also I could notice that we are not trying find it in sh1. Both find functions are routed to sh2. Is that something that needs to looked in to??

Comment: yes i miss it while wrote this code and didnt noticed that You need check arguments from sh2 in sh1. i edited code and made some test in my computer, this time should work.